# Add package path to codeigniter autoload

Tags: php, codeigniter, autoload

I have multiple(two) Codeigniter applications in one project. The directory structure looks like that:

```
applications
--application
--oglasnik
```

I want to use a helper from application in oglasnik.

```
$this->load->add_package_path(APPPATH."../application");
$this->load->helper("string_helper");
$this->load->remove_package_path();
```

This works fine, but i need this helper quite a lot in the application, so is it possible to set a helper from another application in autoload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a relative soft symbolic link in `oglasnik/helpers` named `string_helper.php` that points to `../../../application/helpers/string_helper.php`. This way you can use the normal load method as PHP will think that file exists in the regular helper path, but it actually is the symbolic link pointing to the original one.

See [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-creating-symbolic-link-ln-command/) on how to create a symbolic link.

*(run this in `oglasnik/helpers`)*
Example Command:

```
ln -s ../../../application/helpers/string_helper.php string_helper.php
```

To test that link was created correctly, opening the symbolic link `string_helper.php` created in `oglasnik/helpers` should open the file `string_helper.php` located in `application/helpers`